# Can't jnlp files in fedora open without icedtea

Tags: java, fedora, jnlp, icedtea

its possible to open jnlp file without installed icedtea? I had icedtea, but it wasn't run correctly

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Stepan - You could install sun/oracle jre

Comment: Please distinguish icedtea and icedtea-web. IcedTea is build environment (and much more) around java. But fedora no longer uses it.    If your app did not run with icedtea-web please fill bug in icedtea bugzilla, (woth roper component of icedtea-web, and url we can debug)

Answer (score 0):

You can open it by installing the Oracle JDK. In a normal installation it will be located in `/usr/java/jreX.X.X_YY/bin/javaws` where X.X.X_YY is the java version, or `/usr/java/latest/bin/javaws` if you use that installation method (you will be asked how to during installation).